# How to save an icon image to a location in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am including an icon image in my Resources folder and retrieving it via

```
System.Drawing.Icon icon1= CreateDesktopShortCut.Properties.Resources.Treetog_I_Documents;
```

However After retrieving the icon I want to store the icon to a path in Hard Drive. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Ad: company I work for provides search engine to look for answers on C# questions about saving icons to a file - try it out https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+save+icon+file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the icon's [`Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Icon_Save_System_IO_Stream_) method and a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_):

```
icon1.Save(new FileStream("c:\\myicon.ico", FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Thanks that did it for me..